# Reshape of dataframe where all values not present

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

Let's say I have a dataframe like this - for each sample (which represents an area), there are ten habitat classes (1:10) which can be present in the sample. The dataframe doesn't have an entry for each one, only the ones present in each sample.

```
data <- data.frame(
sample.label = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4),
hclass = c(1, 2, 7, 6, 5, 7, 1, 4, 7, 10), 
cover = c(0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 1, 0.7, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.3))

   sample.label hclass cover
1             1     1  0.2
2             1     2  0.6
3             1     7  0.2
4             2     6  1.0
5             3     5  0.7
6             3     7  0.3
7             4     1  0.2
8             4     4  0.4
9             4     7  0.1
10            4    10  0.3
```

I just need to reshape the dataframe so it looks like this, with a column for each habitat class and added 0s where the class isn't present in the sample:

```
  sample.label class1 class2 class3 class4 class5 class6 class7 class8 class9 class10
1            1    0.2    0.6      0    0.0    0.0      0    0.2      0      0     0.0
2            2    0.0    0.0      0    0.0    0.0      1    0.0      0      0     0.0
3            3    0.0    0.0      0    0.0    0.7      0    0.3      0      0     0.0
4            4    0.2    0.0      0    0.4    0.0      0    0.1      0      0     0.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `complete` + `pivot_wider` from `{tidyr}`.

```r
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  complete(sample.label, hclass = 1:10, fill = list(cover = 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = hclass, names_prefix = "class", values_from = cover)

# # A tibble: 4 × 11
#   sample.label class1 class2 class3 class4 class5 class6 class7 class8 class9 class10
#          <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1            1    0.2    0.6      0    0      0        0    0.2      0      0     0  
# 2            2    0      0        0    0      0        1    0        0      0     0  
# 3            3    0      0        0    0      0.7      0    0.3      0      0     0  
# 4            4    0.2    0        0    0.4    0        0    0.1      0      0     0.3
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks, didn't know about complete()!